# What is the role of lim in the function plt.axis(lim)?

Tags: matplotlib, axis

In my textbook, I have the following code:

```
model = grid.best_estimator_

plt.scatter(X.ravel(), y)
lim = plt.axis()
y_test = model.fit(X, y).predict(X_test)
plt.plot(X_test.ravel(), y_test, hold=True);
plt.axis(lim);
```

I have learnt that plt.axis() is used for setting the axis limits. But what does it mean, when we use this method without a parameter, assign the value to lim and then use lim as a parameter again in plt.axis()?

I don't understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without parameters, [`plt.axis()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) returns the current limits in the x and in the y-direction of the plot.

In this code, these limits are saved into a variable. So, these are the limits into which the scatter plot looks nice.

Then, `plt.plot` is called to draw a specific curve on top of the scatter plot. As this curve also draws outside the region of the scatter plot, matplotlib automatically adjusts its limits to fit the complete curve. But this adjusting will have the scatter plot being reduced to some small region.

To correct the situation, the limits in which the scatter plot looks well are forced again on the plot, using `plt.axis(lim)`.

Here is a visual illustration:

[image: example plots]

Comment: Very clear and very helpful explanation and illustration. Thanks a lot!